# Symfony CollectionType with different fields

Tags: php, collections, symfony, symfony-forms

### Question:

Consider following **Order** form **with so many requirements**:

```
Title:       [_________________]

REQUIREMENTS:

What sizes?   [X] Small     [X] Medium    [_] Large
What shapes?  [_] Circle    [X] Square    [_] Triangle
What colors?  [X] Red       [_] Green     [X] Blue
.
.
.
```

How can I generate and handle the form in **Symfony 3.2**?

### What do I think:

[ Order ] ------**OneToMany**------ [ Requirement ] ------**OneToMany**------ [ Selection ]

**OrderType**

```
class OrderType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $form = $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, array());
            ->add('requirements', CollectionType::class,
                array(
                    'entry_type' => RequirementType::class
                )
            )
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array(();

        return $form;
    }
}
```

### Problem

I don't know how to write the **`RequirementType`**, as they are not exactly the same (**size**, **shape**, **color**, ...).

This is what I think:

**RequirementType**

```
class RequirementType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $form = $builder
            ->add(??????, EntityType::class,
                array(
                    'label'         => ??????,
                    'expanded'      => true,
                    'multiple'      => true,
                    'class'         => Selection::class,
                    'query_builder' => call_user_func(function (EntityRepository $er, $requirement) {
                        return $er->createQueryBuilder('s')
                                 ->where('s.requirement = :requirement')
                                 ->setParameter('requirement', $requirement)
                    },$em->getRepository($args['class']), $requirement);
                )
            );

        return $form;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like Requirement is a ChoiceType with multiple choices allowed.

Comment: 1st make the relation between Order and Requirement a ManyToMany
2nd make a __toString() method in the Requirement entity
3th add a EntityType field to your OrderType and set options expanded=>true and multiple->true http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#expanded

Comment: @FrankB I dont want one entity, I need a collection of similar entities

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand, the requirement’s attributes ("Small", "Medium", "Large"…) are stored in the Collection’ table, and are related to the requirement (“sizes”, “shapes”, “colors” …) with a oneToMany relation (a requirement can have multiple selection) ….

If so, 
the following code works:

**OrderType.php**

```
$builder
    ->add('requirements', CollectionType::class,
        array(
            'entry_type' => RequirementType::class
        )
    );
```

**RequirementType.php :**

```
$builder
    ->add('name',  HiddenType::class, array('disabled'=>true))
    ->add('collections', EntityType::class,  array(
        'class' => ‘AppBundle:Collection’,  
        'choice_label' => 'name', 'multiple' =>true))
```

**In your Twig view :**

```
{{ form_start(orderForm) }}
    {% for requirement in orderForm.requirements %}
        <label>{{ requirement.name.vars.value }}</label>
        {{ form_widget(requirement.collections) }}
        {{ form_widget(requirement.name) }}
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
{{ form_end(orderForm) }}
```

Comment: Sorry, for long delayed response. How does it list all the `Requirement`s?